# How to fix cpanel log in error?

Tags: cpanel

My cpanel  was working fine till yesterday. Today, when I tried logging into it, I got the following error "The filesystem mounted at / on this server is running out of disk space. cPanel operations have been temporarily suspended to prevent something bad from happening. Please ask your system admin to remove any files not in use on that partition".
How do I go about fixing this issue? I am a newbie at this and would be grateful if the solutions were explained in detail, preferably in steps and in layman language if possible.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was solved!! I contacted the host company and they were able to fix it within a few hours.